# Pharo FileSystem: How do I write a binary file?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

```
 TabularResources testExcelSheet
```

from [this project](http://ss3.gemtalksystems.com/ss/Tabular.html) gives me a binary representation in a literal array of an Excel file.

````

testExcelSheet

^ #[80 75 3 4 20 0 6 0 8 0 0 0 33 0 199 122 151 144 120 1 0 0 32 6 0 0 19 0 8 2 91 67 111 110 116 101 110 116 95 84 121 112 101 115 93 46 120 109 108 32 162 4 2 40 160 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .....

....0 109 108 80 75 1 2 45 0 20 0 6 0 8 0 0 0 33 0 126 148 213 45 209 1 0 0 250 10 0 0 16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 233 36 0 0 120 108 47 99 97 108 99 67 104 97 105 110 46 120 109 108 80 75 5 6 0 0 0 0 13 0 13 0 74 3 0 0 232 38 0 0 0 0]

````

### Question

How do I write this to the disk to see which kind of file it is?

### Answer

(by Esteban, edited)

`./TabularATest1.xlsx' asFileReference writeStreamDo: [ :stream | 
    stream 
        binary; 
        nextPutAll: self testExcelSheet ]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Easiest way to do that is something like this:

```
'./file.bin' asFileReference writeStreamDo: [ :stream | 
    stream 
        binary; 
        nextPutAll: #[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0] ]
```

So the trick is just telling to the stream "be a binary file" :)

Comment: Note that there is a compatibility issue at the moment which requires you to use `#binaryReadStream` et. al if you want to *read* binary data.

Comment: @MaxLeske -- could you please elaborate a bit? I added a code snippet based on EstebanLM's answer and it worked.

Comment: For clarification: I was talking about *reading* binary data. The way that read streams are constructed at the moment does not allow switching from ascii to binary mode. Instead, you should use `#binaryReadStream` et. al to get a binary readstream. If you don't do that, you may experience some weird things happening to your data. The plan is to get rid of those extra messages ASAP, but for the moment they are there.